# Consume WCF in .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-framework-version

I want to consume a WCF service in an existing application that is in .Net Framework 4.7.. But I don't see any possibilities because the WCF Web Service Reference option is applicable to projects created using the following project templates:

```
Visual C# > .NET Core
Visual C# > .NET Standard
Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application.
```

Does anyone know a way how to add it for .net Framework?

Comment: WCF was written as a part of .NET 3 (not .NET Core 3) - .NET Framework 3 onwards (and thus: .NET Framework 4.7) absolutely supports WCF; have you tried the "add service reference" option on the project's right-click menu in the solution explorer?

Comment: yes I did, it generates some files but the Reference.cs is empty

Comment: it works only if I add it as Web Reference in Advanced..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to reference the wcf service. [Use the Svcutil tool to generate proxy class calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client), [add service reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019) calls, use [channel factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory) to call, and so on. There are tutorials on the official documents, you can choose the method that suits you to call the wcf service.